# Optimize SQL query, multiple select with differing arguments

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a query like this in a python script

```
results = []
for day in days:
    for hour in hours:
        for id in ids:
             query = "SELECT AVG(weight) from table WHERE date >= '%s' \
                                                          AND day=%s \
                                                          AND hour=%s AND id=%s" % \
                     (paststr, day, hour, _id)
             results.append(query.exec_and_fetch())
```

Or for people not used to python, for every day, for every hour in that day and for all the ids in a list for each of those hours I need to get the average weight for some items.

as an example:

```
day 0 hour 0 id 0
day 0 hour 0 id 1
...
day 2 hour 5 id 4
day 2 hour 6 id 0
...
```

This results in *a lot* of queries, so I'm thinking if it's possible to do this in one query instead.  I've been fiddling a bit with views but I've always got stuck on the varying parameters, or they get so very very slow, it's a rather big table.

My closest guess is this:

```
create or replace view testavg as 
       select date, day, hour, id, (select avg(weight) from cuWeight w_i 
                                        where w_i.date=w_o.date 
                                           and w_i.day=w_o.day 
                                           and w_i.hour=w_o.hour) 
       from cuWeight w_o;
```

But that hasn't returned anything yet, after waiting a minute or two I cancel the query.

table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `cuWeight` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date default NULL,
  `hour` int(11) default '0',
  `weight` float default '0',
  `day` int(11) default '0',
  KEY `id_index` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

myisam and latin1 are for historical(almost fossilised) reasons.

Comment: Show us the create table statement and example data (http://sqlfiddle.com), information about storage engine in use. and define your question better not everybody can read python code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` query

```
select date, day, hour, id, avg(weight)
   from cuWeight
   where date > *some date*
group by date, day, hour, id ;
```

If it's still slow you can split it up in chunks, for example:

```
for day in days:
    query = "select date, day, hour, id, avg(weight) \
                from cuWeight \
                where date > '%s' \
                  and day = %s \
                group by date, day, hour, id " % \
            (paststr, day)
...
```